# Extract a value from @Message as float in logsearch and in Kibana calculate the sum from that extracted value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok

I have a value in my @message part that I need to extract out and then provide the sum of that value for that day. I have written below in my filters-default.conf file

```
if "NETAMT" in [@message] {
 grok {
  match => { "@message" => "<NETAMT>(?<NETAMT>.*?)<\/NETAMT>" }
 }
 mutate {
  convert => [ "NETAMT", "float" ]
 }
}
```

The field starts appearing in the Kibana UI [![NETAMT Field][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3uHH.jpg

Now when I am trying to sum it using STATS panel, it always gives 0. 
[![Panel Setting][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWNQv.jpg

[![Stats Data][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTthu.jpg

Can anyone help here, please?

Comment: what kibana version are you using?

Comment: Kibana version 4

Comment: have you checked the time filter? this happened to me when i wanted to sum values that were stored yesterday and the time filter was 15 mins ago. I use kibana 6.3.3 and it has a different gui than yours. I suggest you make an update.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved after refreshing the index through kibana so that the new field becomes indexable and searchable.